# Is it possible to create a new Type in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a new type, i. e:

```
[sbyte  (1 Byte) Value-range :        -128 to +127]
[byte   (1 Byte) Value-range :           0 to +255]    
[short  (2 Byte) Value-range :      -32768 to +32767]
[ushort (2 Byte) Value-range :           0 to +65535]    
[int    (4 Byte) Value-range : -2147483648 to +2147483647]
[uint   (4 Byte) Value-range :           0 to +4294967295]
.
.
.
etc.
```

now I want to create LInt(LowInt) Type in range 0 to 200000, so I dont want to use uint or int.

Is it any possible with C#?

Thank You!

Comment: While it is possible to create that, just curious if there is any reason you don't want to use `int` for that?

Comment: I looked into this exact thing, but there's no real way to emulate an integral/primitive type.  You can emulate some parts of it (with a struct, implementing key interfaces, etc.) but you can't quite get it all.

Comment: It almost sounds you like something like a `FixedRange` class, wherein values can only be between `[min, max]`, or permutations of closed and open end points. If that's what you want, it's quite easy to create such a thing.

Comment: @Mike: What happens when you add/subtract/multiply two such types?  What if they have different ranges to begin with?  Would you expect a third type to pop out (bigger *or* smaller range than both inputs)?  Would you expect the result's range to be a union or intersection of both ranges?  Any possible answer isn't widely applicable, so I wouldn't bother creating the type unless it was domain specific.  It also doesn't solve the problem of validating multiple-value constraints.  See my answer.

Comment: Also see [does-any-programming-language-support-defining-constraints-on-primitive-data-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422380/does-any-programming-language-support-defining-constraints-on-primitive-data-typ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in a built-in way, using simple language, e.g. `int<5000,20000>`.

While it is possible with a more complex definition, it isn't easy.  It is difficult to determine and define all the semantics you'd want, such as:

- Conversion to other ranged types
- Conversion from built in numeric types
- What should happen on overflow/underflow
- What should the resulting type's range be after arithmetic is performed

Such a solution also wouldn't cover cases where you'd want one parameter's type range be constrained based on another parameter's value.

An alternative would be to use something like [`Code Contracts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts) to define contracts for your code so you can do arbitrary static (compile time) verifications.

*Edit*: Removed link to SpecSharp.  It looks like it was replaced with Code Contracts...

Comment: You may also want to take a look at operator overloading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467.aspx

Comment: @Polynomial: While what you say is true, I made the assumption anyone trying to replace built-in numeric types would already know how to do that.  If you read my answer more carefully, I basically am saying "don't bother - it is a really bad idea".  I know because I've tried it before :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is what classes are for.  Now, you cannot create a new "builtin" type.  The semantics may not be exactly the same, but I'm guessing you won't care too much about those differences.

Comment: I was meaning the Primitive Types

Comment: He could create a struct for it to be a value type and the syntax and semantics can be made to be very similar to that of built in types.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a struct to create a "type", but you are not able to create a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and handle your conditions, if you want it to act more like a primitive try making it a struct

Answer (score 0):

It is of no use. Your CPU architecture defines what chunks of data it can handle at once and for what purposes. Even if you created a type that only allowed for different min-max values (which you can implement in a class and operator overloading), it would not be more efficient in neither memory nor performance aspects.

If you want to simply enforce some semantics, here's something that should lead in you the right direction (it's by no means complete, and lacks support for the *checked* and *unchecked* keywords).

```
struct MyInt
{
    static uint max = 200000;
    readonly uint i;
    public MyInt(uint i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyInt(uint j) {
        if(j > max)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        return new MyInt(j);
    }

    public static MyInt operator +(MyInt i, uint j) {
        try {
            return new MyInt(i.i + j);
        }
        catch(ArgumentException) {
            throw new OverflowException();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return i.ToString();
    }
}
```